# Generated SVG image doesn't display

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm developing a JavaScript class to show all SVG objects, but when I create the element "image", the browser doesn't display it. Though if I copy the generated code and put it in another document, the image is displayed.

When I searched the image using Firebug's inspector, the object appears but the image is not displayed.

I created the object using `appendChild()`, `setAttribute()` and `setAttributeNS()`

This is the generated code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="100%" width="100%" >
<image width="50" height="50" xlink:href="logo.png" y="20" x="20" id="d"></image>
</svg>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Show us your code for creating the SVG.  Are you using `createElementNS()` when creating the SVG elements?

Answer (score 1):

The problem were the namespaces. This is the correct form to create images dynamically:

```
image.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', 'flower.png');
```

More imformation can be found on [MDN's 'Namespaces Crash Course'](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course).